# jpql @query case when

Tags: jpa, jpql

I'm implementing search method in JPQL which searches for all of objects of  Institution class,from given parameter in two of the fields of class. In case there are no objects it should return null. This code works but returns empty collection instead of null.

```
@Query("select  i from Institution i where i.city like concat('%', :pattern, '%') or " +
        "i.name like concat('%', :pattern, '%') ")
List<Institution> findAll(@Param("pattern") String criteria);
```

So itried this way which seems to be working, but its not.

```
  @Query("select case when((i.city like concat('%', :pattern, '%')) or (i.name like concat('%', :pattern, '%' )) ) " +
        "then i else null END " +
        "from Institution i")
List<Institution> findAll(@Param("pattern") String criteria);
```

Comment: Why do you do the condition in the select clause and not in the where clause?

Comment: Sorry my bad, i forgot about the first way

Answer (score 0):

JPA always returns empty collections. Spring Data JPA is calling query.getResultList()

```
getResultList
java.util.List getResultList()
Execute a SELECT query and return the query results as an untyped List.
Returns:
a list of the results
Throws:
IllegalStateException - if called for a Java Persistence query language UPDATE or DELETE statement
QueryTimeoutException - if the query execution exceeds the query timeout value set and only the statement is rolled back
TransactionRequiredException - if a lock mode has been set and there is no transaction
PessimisticLockException - if pessimistic locking fails and the transaction is rolled back
LockTimeoutException - if pessimistic locking fails and only the statement is rolled back
PersistenceException - if the query execution exceeds the query timeout value set and the transaction is rolled back
```

It's bad practice to return null if the return type is a collection because the consumer of your method assumes that in case of no element the collection is empty.

So why do you want to return null?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for advice Simon :) . I found a mistake. In a service class layer i forgot to check out if there are blank characters. So the controller was returning whole List converted to dto from database. The first solve is correct it. It demanded only this:

```
 public List<InstitutionDTO> findAll(String criteria) {
   if(criteria.trim().length() == 0) {
       throw new InstitutionSearchNotFoundException();
   }
```